# javascript callback not pushing data up to the top of the calls

Tags: javascript

I am slowly learning how to use callbacks and I am running into trouble. I think the code below should work byt it is not.

From what I can tell it is not descending in to the recursive function as when it hit another 'tree' entry or outputting anything at the end.

One of the issues I ran into is the callback in the for loop. I was not sure that there is a better way to do it: I just used a counter to see if I was at the end of the loop before calling the callback.

Some guidance would be really appreciated.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var objectsList = [];

    function makeAJAXCall(hash, cb) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            accept: 'application/vnd.github.raw',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: hash,
            success: function (json) {

                if (cb) {
                    cb(json);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        });
    }

    function parseBlob(hash, cb) {
        makeAJAXCall(hash, function (returnedJSON) {  // no loop as only one entry
            if (cb) {
                cb(returnedJSON.data);
            }
        });
    }

    function complete(cb, loopLength, treeContents) {
        concole.info(loopLength);
        if (cb && loopLength === 0) {
            objectsList.push(treeContents);
            cb();
        }
    }

    function parseTree(hash, treeName, cb) {
        var treeContents = {'tree': treeName, 'blobs': []}, loopLength, i, entry;
        var tree = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/SVG-Shapes/git/trees/' + hash;
        makeAJAXCall(tree, function (returnedJSON) {
            loopLength = returnedJSON.data.tree.length;
            for (i = 0;  i < returnedJSON.data.tree.length; i += 1) {
                entry = returnedJSON.data.tree[i];
                if (entry.type === 'blob') {
                    if (entry.path.slice(-4) === '.svg') {     // we only want the svg images not the ignore file and README etc
                        parseBlob(entry.url, function (json) {
                            treeContents.blobs.push(json.content);
                            loopLength -= 1;
                            complete(hash, loopLength, cb);
                        });
                    }
                } else if (entry.type === 'tree') {
                    parseTree(entry.sha, entry.path, function () {console.info(objectsList);});
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        parseTree('master', 'master', function () {     // master to start at the top and work our way down
            console.info(objectsList);
        });
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion will not work properly because the variable where you are collecting blob data `treeContents` is a local variable of the recursive function so it's created new and destroyed on every call to `parseTree()`.  It will not be accumulating data.  You must create this variable outside the scope of the `parseTree()` function so a single instance of this variable can live from one call to the next and you can correctly accumulate data in it.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. You can pass the current state of `treeContents` into the `parseTree()` function
2. You can make the recursive part of the function be a local function that shares a common `treeContents` variable.
3. You can make the `treeContents` variable be a global variable.

The second is my choice here something like this:

```
function parseTree(topHash, topTreeName, topCb) {
    var treeContents = {'tree': toptreeName, 'blobs': []};

    function parse(hash, treeName, cb) {
        var loopLength, i, entry;
        var tree = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/SVG-Shapes/git/trees/' + hash;
        makeAJAXCall(tree, function (returnedJSON) {
            loopLength = returnedJSON.data.tree.length;
            for (i = 0;  i < returnedJSON.data.tree.length; i += 1) {
                entry = returnedJSON.data.tree[i];
                if (entry.type === 'blob') {
                    if (entry.path.slice(-4) === '.svg') {     // we only want the svg images not the ignore file and README etc
                        parseBlob(entry.url, function (json) {
                            treeContents.blobs.push(json.content);
                            loopLength -= 1;
                            complete(hash, loopLength, cb);
                        });
                    }
                } else if (entry.type === 'tree') {
                    parse(entry.sha, entry.path, function () {console.info(objectsList);});
                }
            }
        });
    }

    parse(topHash, topTreeName, topCb);
}
```

Assuming the ajax call is asynchronous, you will still need to find a way to know when you're done with all the parsing and call some function that you pass the `treeContents` data to because otherwise, that data is not available to any other function.  It can't be simply returned from parseTree because of the asynch nature of the ajax calls.